# UWP Page Transition, Change Animation Direction

Tags: c#, uwp, win-universal-app

I have UWP app that I use Frame.Navigate() method a lot. By default it seems to be performing transitions with an animation that makes next screen appear sliding from bottom. However, for my case it makes more sense if next screen comes from right or left.

So, to change this default behaviour, I used the following code from [this MSDN document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/motion/page-transitions):

```
// Navigate to the right, ie. from LeftPage to RightPage
myFrame.Navigate(typeof(RightPage), null, new SlideNavigationTransitionInfo() { SlideNavigationTransitionEffect.FromRight } );

// Navigate to the left, ie. from RightPage to LeftPage
myFrame.Navigate(typeof(LeftPage), null, new SlideNavigationTransitionInfo() { SlideNavigationTransitionEffect.FromLeft } );
```

but I get this error:

> Cannot initialize type 'SlideNavigationTransitionInfo' with a
>   collection initializer because it does not implement
>   'System.Collections.IEnumerable'

Changing code like this

```
myFrame.Navigate(typeof(RightPage), null, new SlideNavigationTransitionInfo() { Effect = SlideNavigationTransitionEffect.FromRight } );
```

causes app to crash by Invalid cast exception.

This was an old app that I'm updating so I suspected that might cause the issue and I updated the target version. Now targetting section looks like:

Target version: 1809 (10.0; Build 17763);

Min version : (10.0; 10240)

but still, problem persists.
Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: What is the exact error of Invalid cast exception? From which type to which type?

Comment: It says Unable to cast object of type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Animation.SlideNavigationTransitionInfo' to type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Animation.ISlideNavigationTransitionInfo2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you prefer , You can simply use XAML page transitions, its also compatible with min version 10240:
just put below lines in your **RightPage** or **LeftPage** XAML source.

```
<Page.Transitions>
   <TransitionCollection>
      <EdgeUIThemeTransition Edge="Left">
      </EdgeUIThemeTransition>   
   </TransitionCollection>
</Page.Transitions>
```

Answer (score 6):

The first syntax error is quite self-explanatory; while the InvalidCastException seems to be caused by the fact that you are running you code on an OS with a version lower than 1809.

[SlideNavigationTransitionEffect Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.animation.slidenavigationtransitioneffect) was added in 1809. You can compile your code successfully because you have installed the SDK for 1809, but at runtime, if you don’t check beforehand, this code fails if runtime doesn’t support it.

```
//remove this from your code and it should be running well
Effect = SlideNavigationTransitionEffect.FromRight
```

In this case, you can set the Min version as 1809, to enforce this app can only be installed on 1809 or higher. Or you can write [version adaptive code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/version-adaptive-code) to check the OS support for the API, in this way, you can keep you Min version as low as desired to target a wider range of devices.

Comment: This seems to be the issue.

Comment: Thanks for such a comprehensive answer +1. It also helped me to solve my other issues related to this OS version problem. However other solution is simple and eliminates backward compatability issue, I think it is better for googlers.